# What causes delayed results as per indian astrology?

Tags: astrology

My life has become very slow, even to get 10 rupees result I have been waiting months and months without any positive or negative outcome.

It is causing me to struggle between good and bad.

Are there any special planets that causes this kind of dilemma in one's life?